# Kyoto Cabinet install via rubygems fails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, kyotocabinet

I am trying to install Kyoto Cabinet via ruby gems. I am putting inside the Gemfile

```
gem "kyotocabinet", "~> 1.0"
```

as opposed [here](http://rubygems.org/gems/kyotocabinet)
but when I run `bundle` it fails with

```
setting variables ...
$CFLAGS = -I. -I/usr/local/include -Wall $(cflags)  -fPIC -O2
$LDFLAGS = -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -L. -L/usr/local/lib
$libs =  -lkyotocabinet -lz -lstdc++ -lrt -lpthread -lm -lc
checking for kccommon.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -I/home/gerry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/home/gerry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/gerry/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_KCCOMMON_H    -fPIC -I. -I/usr/local/include -Wall -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC -O2   -o kyotocabinet.o -c kyotocabinet.cc
kyotocabinet.cc:29: error: ‘INT32_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
kyotocabinet.cc:30: error: ‘INT32_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
kyotocabinet.cc:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
kyotocabinet.cc:320: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
kyotocabinet.cc: In function ‘void init_err()’:
kyotocabinet.cc:387: error: ‘NOFILE’ is not a member of ‘kyotocabinet::BasicDB::Error’
kyotocabinet.cc: In function ‘VALUE db_increment(int, VALUE*, VALUE)’:
kyotocabinet.cc:1009: error: ‘INT64_MIN’ was not declared in this scope
kyotocabinet.cc: In function ‘VALUE db_synchronize(int, VALUE*, VALUE)’:
kyotocabinet.cc:1094: error: cannot declare variable ‘proc’ to be of abstract type ‘SoftFileProcessor’
kyotocabinet.cc:288: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘SoftFileProcessor’:
/usr/local/include/kcdb.h:1070: note:   virtual bool
kyotocabinet::BasicDB::FileProcessor::process(const std::string&, int64_t, int64_t)
make: *** [kyotocabinet.o] Error 1
```

If anyone knows a way to bypass this error please help! I am using Ubuntu 10.10 FYI.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the gem "kyotocabinet-ruby" instead.

Comment: This still seems to fail on my machine.  Is there a new gem?

Comment: See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788108/407213 (you need the `libkyotocabinet-dev` package)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `libkyotocabinet-dev` package:

`sudo apt-get install libkyotocabinet-dev`

And then you can use `kyotocabinet-ruby`:

`sudo gem install kyotocabinet-ruby`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without relying on debian packages?  Can header files be installed any other way?

Comment: To be fair, I think you should not use this gem, it's not maintained anymore: last update in August 2011 (see http://rubygems.org/gems/kyotocabinet-ruby)